# Provide strings stored in a file as a list of arguments to a command?

Tags: shell, xargs, arguments, stdin

I install a list of URLs in a text file named `myurls`:

```
http://www.examples.com/1
http://www.examples.com/2
http://www.examples.com/3
```

How shall I pass these URLs to `wkhtmltopdf` as inputs?

The direct way without using a file to store the URLs is

```
wkhtmltopdf http://www.examples.com/1 http://www.examples.com/2 http://www.examples.com/3 all.pdf
```

Maybe `wkhtmltopdf` has special requirements on its arguments, but I think my question may be more general than  `wkhtmltopdf`:
how to provide a list of (new line separated) strings stored in a file as a list of arguments to a command?

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```sh
# disable shell filename generation (globbing) 
# and temporarily save applicable shell state
set -f -- "-${-:--}" "${IFS+IFS=\$2;}" "$IFS" "$@"

# explicitly set the shell's Internal
# Field Separator to only a newline 
eval "IFS='$(printf \\n\')"

# split command substitution into an
# arg array at $IFS boundaries while
# eliding all blank lines in myurls
wkhtmltopdf $(cat <myurls) allurl.pdf

# restore current shell to precmd state
unset IFS; set +f "$@"; eval "$1 shift 2"
```

That's extra cautious about restoring all shell state after possibly altering universally applied attributes. But the basic precept is just to set the shell's splitter in `$IFS`, to take care *not* to glob in case any of the command substitution's expansion includes `[?*`, and then to expand it unquoted into a list of arguments.

It can be done robustly much more simply in a subshell because you don't have to live with any after-effects:

```sh
(   set -f; IFS='
';  wkhtmltopdf $(cat) allurl.pdf
)   <myurls
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, my mistake, need literal newline here. What do you mean about using tab?

Comment: Ah, of course. But the OP want a general solution- *how to provide a list of (new line separated) strings stored in a file as a list of arguments to a command?* - so I stick with limiting it to newline.

Comment: @mikeserv: Feel free to edit it for better approach, I'm not in my PC now.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately it's not the case with `wkhtmltopdf`, but many commands provide an option to read arguments from a file (`wget -i` for example); that's the preferred approach where possible.

If whitespace in your file isn't important, command substitution works:

```
wkhtmltopdf $(cat myurls) all.pdf
```

Using `xargs` would also work with your example, but in general given what you're trying to do you'd need to ensure that it only runs `wkhtmltopdf` once; `all.pdf` will only contain the pages from the last run of `wkhtmltopdf`:

```
xargs -a myurls sh -c 'wkhtmltopdf "$@" all.pdf'
```

`wkhtmltopdf` [does support an option to read arguments from standard input](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt), `--read-args-from-stdin`. If you use that to feed it URLs separated by newlines, it repeats executions; to avoid that, you need to ensure that standard input is a single line with all URLs separated by spaces:

```
tr "\n" " " < myurls | wkhtmltopdf --read-args-from-stdin all.pdf
```

Answer (score 1):

With `xargs`:

```
xargs -a myurls sh -c 'wkhtmltopdf $@ all.pdf'
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach:

```
wkhtmltopdf $(printf '%s ' $(<myurls)) all.pdf
```

Comment: Why do this instead of `wkhtmltopdf $(<myurls) all.pdf`?