# How to read multiples arguments per line for a bash command?

Tags: mv, for

I have a file (ordered_names) which is in the format

```
pub 000.html
pub.19 001.html
```

for about 300 lines, And I can't find a way to feed this to the mv command.

I have read [Provide strings stored in a file as a list of arguments to a command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/210455/provide-strings-stored-in-a-file-as-a-list-of-arguments-to-a-command), but I could not get what I came for.

Here are some of the attempts I made :

```
for line in "$(cat ../ordered_files.reversed)"; do mv  $(echo "$line"); done
for line in "$(cat ../ordered_files.reversed)"; do echo mv $(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f 1) $(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f 2) ; done
```

Comment: This is [BashFAQ 001](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). See also [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice). The basic problem is the same, but of course `find -exec` doesn't work with cat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
while read -r file1 file2; do mv -n -- "$file1" "$file2"; done <inputfile
```

This assumes that the file names on each line in the input file are space-separated.  This, of course, only works if the file names themselves do not contain spaces.  If they do, then you need a different input format.

#### How it works

- `while read -r file1 file2; do`

  This starts a `while` loop.  The loop continues as long as input is available.  For each line of input, two parameters are read: `file1` and `file2`.
- `mv -n -- "$file1" "$file2"`

  This moves `file1` to `file2`.

  The option `-n` protects you from overwriting any file at the destination.  Of course, if it is your intention to overwrite files, remove this option.

  The string `--` signals the end of the options.  This protects you from problems should any of the file names start with a `-`.
- `done`

  This signals the end of the `while` loop.
- `<inputfile`

  This tells the `while` loop to gets its input from a file called `inputfile`.

Comment: I always recommend using `mv -n` or `mv -i` for bulk moves like this, to avoid accidental overwriting (silent & irreversible) of files due to name conflicts. In this case, `mv -i` would try to read overwrite confirmations from the file list, which wouldn't work well at all, so `mv -n` is the way to go.

Comment: @GordonDavisson Excellent point.  I just added `-n` added to the answer.